# setClassUnion fails joining a glm with a coxph class

Tags: r, r-s4, roxygen2

When I try to create a class in R, containing a slot that should accept either a `glm` class object or a `coxph` class one I get an error during package build that is 
`Error in setClassUnion(name = "glmORcoxph", members = c("glm", "coxph")) : the member classes must be defined: not true of "coxph"`.
I tried to put `@import`, `@importClassesFrom`, `@importFrom` Roxygen directives to my source code but without success. This is the code I use for creating my `DoseVolumeModel` class:

```
setClassUnion(name = "ConfidenceInterval", members = c("NULL", "numeric"))
setClassUnion(name = "glmORcoxph", members = c("glm", "coxph"))
setClass("DoseVolumeModel", 
     representation(
       output.matrix = "matrix",
       fitted.model = "glmORcoxph",
       fitted.value = "numeric",
       CI = "ConfidenceInterval",
       fitted.parameter = "character"
     )
)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: the answer is likely to be running `setOldClass("coxph")` before your `setClassUnion` --- S3 classes aren't suitable for inclusion in class unions and slots until you run `setOldClass` on them.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like running now. However the package build exits with a warning `Warning: Classes.R:26: Missing name`, but I don't know what does it mean as `name`

Comment: No idea. Is that definitely related to this issue? Is this snippet of code at line 26 of `Classes.R`?

Comment: That is my code, the 1st line is the 26th line in the source file: 
`setOldClass(Classes = "coxph")
setClassUnion(name = "ConfidenceInterval", members = c("NULL", "numeric"))
setClassUnion(name = "glmORcoxph", members = c("glm", "coxph"))
setClass("DoseVolumeModel", 
         representation(
           output.matrix = "matrix",
           fitted.model = "glmORcoxph",
           fitted.value = "numeric",
           CI = "ConfidenceInterval",
           fitted.parameter = "character"
         )
)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use S3 classes like `coxph` unless they have been pre-registered. You can do this by calling

```
setOldClass("coxph")
```

before your calls to `setClassUnion`. Then you are free to use `coxph` as a class definition in slots or class unions.

Note that you cannot guarantee much about such `coxph` objects as R does not enforce that they have any particular properties. Any user is free to do something like

```
x <- 1
class(x) <- "coxph"
```

(or take a real `coxph` object and `NULL` out parts of it)

and they will still be valid inputs to your classes. You might want to implement some input checking to take account of this.